# Looking for Dynamic Stored Procedure, to use for multiple queries

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic, cobol

I want to design a dynamic stored procedure, where I will be passing the column name, table name and my where clause. So that I can use the stored procedure to run select on different table with different parameters.

I'm not sure if this is possible. If yes, anyone will able to help me with example.

For example.

Query 1: `Select name, number, total into out_name, out_number, out_total from student where total > 100;`

Query 2: `select book into out_book from lib where cost > 100;`

I should able to execute above queries in single stored procedure by passing the `column`, `table` and `where` clause.

I created something like below. I did something like this for delete, delete working fine.

```
SET V_SELECT =                                         
  'SELECT ' || SELECT_FIELDS ||                        
  ' FROM '  || TABLE_NAME    ||                        
  ' WHERE ' || WHERE_CLAUSE  ||                        
  ' WITH UR';                                          

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SELECT INTO || INTO_FIELDS   ||;
```

Comment: Thats a really really bad design pattern for SQL. Yes you can do it, but I can't think of any circumstances under which it would be a good idea. I know its tempting to try and build generic SQL mechanisms, but its not the way SQL is designed to work.

Comment: @DaleK, Thanks for checking. I'm converting two sub-routines into stored procedure. I have 10 different simple select quires in it.I don't want to create 10 select statement, Generic select and pass a parameter required. Sounds simple but challenging.

Comment: You are definitely better off creating 10 select statements. That way you 1) get full compile type checking, 2) can optimise for performance easily and 3) Remove the risk of screwing your database because you passed an incorrect parameter in.

Comment: However if you are set on this path, please google dynamic SQL tutorial and have a go at building something. There is plenty of help out there but you can't expect someone to write it for you.

Comment: The amount of extra code you would have to write and complexity will far outweigh the 10 queries. Having said that, there are tools that do it, namely [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) tools such as [Entity Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework).

Comment: It seems to me your design is mixed up if you want to put 10 unrelated queries in the same SP. Consider the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

Comment: @Alex,Thanks for the response. ORM?. I'm calling my stored procedure using COBOL program. Will I able to use ORM in this case. If yes, Will you able to help me with samples.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_DynamicProc
(
    @SelectFields NVARCHAR(1024)
    , @IntoTableName NVARCHAR(255)
    , @TableName NVARCHAR(255)
    , @WhereClause NVARCHAR(1024)
)
AS
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT ' + @SelectFields + ISNULL(' INTO ' + @IntoTableName,'') + ' FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @WhereClause
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Highly highly dangerous... totally open to an injection attack.

Comment: I agree, terrible idea.  That was not what the question was.

Comment: As an expert you should always be pointing out how OP can improve. And when writing dynamic SQL you should be using `QUOTENAME` at a minimum.

Comment: @DaleK, Got SQLCODE = -104, ERROR:  ILLEGAL SYMBOL "=". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT 
BE LEGAL ARE: ( * AT YEAR YEARS MONTH MONTHS DAY DAYS HOUR HOURS